# Struggling with jquery Show (), hide() and toggle()

Tags: jquery

am building some functionality/website that I could use some help. I got it working how I need it to, but I figure that it's really crude so any help making it cleaner is appreciated.

Here is the HTML.

```
     <div class="large-5 columns">
          <div id="t1" class="t1">
            <h3>
              <a href="#">
                Link one
              </a>
            </h3>
            <p id="r1">
              Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
          </div>
 <div id="t2" class="t2">
            <h3>
              <a href="#">
                Link two
              </a>
            </h3>
            <p id="r2">
              Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div> <div id="imageone" style="display:none">
```

first image in tab

and Here is the Jquery:
I'll have more tabs but just kept it like this for now.

```
 <script>
$( "#t1 a" ).click(function() {
$( "#r1" ).toggle()
$( "#r2" ).hide()
$( "#imageone" ).show()
});


</script>
```

here is a JSFIDDLE, it works how I need it to work, but I feel like it's really crude in terms of my Javascript, can anyone help me re-write this to be simpler code?
http://jsfiddle.net/2jbf9cx0/

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? You question is unclear :)

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/z5zrp4pp/ ?

Comment: You want it more generic so it's scalable and you don't have to target everything by a unique `id`?

Comment: sorry for not being clearer fellas, i'll adjust my post.

Comment: Sparky - Yes, more generic, but the thing is, there is an image in another location as well that corresponds to each tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using the data attribute http://jsfiddle.net/2jbf9cx0/2/

```
    $(".mytabs p").hide()
        $('.t').on('click', function () {
            $('.t p, .timg').hide();
            $(this).find('p').show();
            $('.timg[data-tag=' + $(this).data("tag") + ']').show();
    });
```

Check the html on the fiddle for additional modifications on the code :)

Comment: thanks Bojan! Perfect, any chance you could explain what happends inside that fuction. Ie, "            $('.timg[data-tag=' + $(this).data("tag") + ']').show();"

Comment: You have a data attribute on all of your images and .t class tags, on click on the .t div it will look for the image that has the same data attribute (data-tag) and show it

Comment: You will give the same data attribute to the corespondent div and image you want to show when clicked. So if your div has a data-tag="t1", it will look for an image that has the same data-tag="t1" and it will show it :)

Comment: ok, some more questions: why use on() rather than click? Also, "this" means the current element being clicked?

Comment: Correct :) That line does that. $(this).data("tag") is the data attribute value of the clicked element and we search for an element with the same data value and show it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should never need to hard-wire to ids when you have similar items. Use classes and the hierarchy to use a single handler that can find the matching elements.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2jbf9cx0/4/

Annotated code:

```
  // Initial hide of all .info paragraphs
  $(".info").hide()

  // If any anchor in a .tab is clicked
  $(".tab a").click(function () {
        // Find the closest ancestor .tab
        var $tab = $(this).closest('.tab');

        // then the .info in that .tab
        var $info = $tab.find('.info');

        // Hide all the other infos (not excludes the target one)
        $('.info').not($info).hide();

        // Toggle the specific info
        $info.toggle();

        // Use a the id of the tab to find a matching image with data-id attribute
        var $image = $('[data-id=' + $tab.attr('id') + ']');

        // Hide all but the selected image
        $('images').not($image).hide();

        // Show the selected image (or toggle if you prefer)
        $image.show();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Aussie! I know, I just didn't understand how to do it right.

Comment: your comments really helped, but I wasn't sure how to do the showing images as well. ...

Comment: Yes, I was in the middle of that. Updated. You needed to allow enough time for the answers to settle :)